# Storing Multiple solutions from Solve as rows of a matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, diophantine-equations

I am trying to find all the solutions to a Diophantine equation (only integer valued solutions) using Solve[], however there are multiple and even many solutions sometimes.

How can I store these individual solutions as rows of a matrix?

When I apply the rules to the variables, and then display as table, or matrix, and then get the dimension of the resulting "table", it appears that it is just one long vector, and not a matrix as it appears.

For example:
Solve[2/3-1/x-1/y-1/z==0 &&x>=1 &&y>=x &&z>=y,{x,y,z},Integers]. This produces 8 solutions of the form (x,y,z). So I would like each solution to be an individual row in an 8x3 matrix.

Comment: `Solve[2/3 - 1/x - 1/y - 1/z == 0 && x >= 1 && y >= x && z >= y, {x, y,
    z}, Integers][[All, All, 2]]`, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eq = 2/3 - 1/x - 1/y - 1/z == 0 && x >= 1 && y >= x && z >= y;
var = {x, y, z};
(mat = var /. Solve[eq, var, Integers]) // MatrixForm
Dimensions[mat]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  2 & 7 & 42 \\
>  2 & 8 & 24 \\
>  2 & 9 & 18 \\
>  2 & 10 & 15 \\
>  2 & 12 & 12 \\
>  3 & 4 & 12 \\
>  3 & 6 & 6 \\
>  4 & 4 & 6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>   {8, 3}

Comment: I have done that, but when I go to store this as a matrix, it turns out to be a 1x24 matrix with just each row appended to each other.

Comment: @MatthewCrawford The above code yields a 8x3 matrix. What code did you use?

Comment: Table3=({x,y,z}/. Solve[2/3-1/x-1/y-1/z==0 && x>=1 && y>=x && z>=y,{x,y,z},Integers])//MatrixForm
Dimensions[Table3]

Comment: You store a `MatrixForm` in `Table3`, because `// MatrixForm` has higher precedence than `Table3 = `. If you left click 3 times fast on "//" you can see how the code is parsed